# Cannot open database "ASPNETDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Philip-Desktop\Philip'

Tags: asp.net, sql, security, authentication

I'm been struggling to find an answer to this problem for hours now...

I use to not get this error while accessing the ASPNETDB database, but unfortunately I don't know what I changed. The error comes up when I try to access a file called Admin.aspx I have in a folder called Admin. I had restrictions set on this folder using the Web Site Administration Tool, but when the error came up I took them all of them off to see what the problem was and I still get the error?? The Admin.aspx file is the only one that gets the error..

My connection string in web.config is:

```
<add name="WIJLConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is the error:

> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Cannot open database "ASPNETDB"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user
>   'Philip-Desktop\Philip'.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot
>   open database "ASPNETDB" requested by
>   the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user
>   'Philip-Desktop\Philip'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +5009598    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   +234    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2275
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) +35
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection
>   owningObject) +183
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +195
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +232
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +185
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +524
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +66
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +479
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +108
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   +125    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +123
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32
>   maxRecords, String srcTable,
>   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +319
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, String srcTable) +92
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1618
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments,
>   DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>   +21    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   +143    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>   +74    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
>   +4    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   +66    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
>   +102    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +42    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +175    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +175    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

Someone please help!! I'm desperate at this point

Answer (score 11):

The error message is as clear as it can be:

> Cannot open database "ASPNETDB"
>   requested by the login. The login
>   failed. **Login failed for user
>   'Philip-Desktop\Philip'**

That Windows user isn't allowed to connect to that database and use it.

Check to make sure:

- that you have the proper server name in your connection string. Is it really `localhost`? Or did you perhaps install SQL Server Express and it ended up being `(local)\SQLExpress` instead??
- that the **server** you're connecting to has a login for `Philip-Desktop\Philip` (check in `Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Security -> Logins`)
- that the **database** ASPNETDB has a user based on that login so that you can use that database (check in `Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Databases -> (your database) -> Security -> Users`)
- that your `admin.aspx` page is truly referencing that connection string you've given (`WIJLConnectionString1`). Is there by any chance a separate `web.config` in your `Admin` folder that e.g. has a different connection string, and the `admin.aspx` page references that connection string instead??

Comment: @Philip906: `localhost`, `(local)` and `.` should all be equivalent; question is: is your SQL Server installed as the main/default instance without separate instance name, or did you install e.g. Express, which defaults to an `SQLExpress` instance name (which you need to add to your server name, to connect to it)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response I figured out what was wrong.

Apparently all my SqlDataSource connection strings, inside of the Admin.aspx, had changed from using the connection string that pointed at the correct database (WIJL), to the connection string WIJLConnectionString1 which pointed at the ASPNETDB database. All I had to do was just change the connections strings back

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Running the model-creation wizard can cause this under certain circumstances.